# different values for float and double

Tags: java

I don't understand why are float values different from double values. From the example bellow it appears that float provides different result than double for the same operation:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double a = 99999.8d;
        double b = 99999.65d;
        System.out.println(a + b);

        float a2 = 99999.8f;
        float b2 = 99999.65f;
        System.out.println(a2 + b2);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
199999.45
199999.44
```

Can you explain what makes this difference between float and double?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Single-precision_32_bit

Comment: What the others said, but in your specific case the result is wider than the number of significant digits possible with floats (cfr wikipedia, 7.2 digits) - see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision

Comment: thx all for your hints, those wiki articles are interesting

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A float is a 32 bit IEEE 754 floating point.

A double is a 64 bit IEEE 754 floating point.

so it is just a matter of precision because neither of the fraction portions .8 and .65 have a terminating binary representation, so there is some rounding error. the double has more precision so it has slightly less rounding error.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 14):

> Can you explain what makes this difference between float and double?

Sure. Imagine you had two *decimal* types, one with five significant digits, and one with ten.

What value would you use to represent pi for each of those types? In both cases you'd be trying to get as close to a number which you couldn't represent *exactly* - but you wouldn't end up with the same value, would you?

It's the same for `float` and `double` - both are binary floating point types, but `double` has more precision than `float`.

Comment: +1 A better example; `one with 6 significant digits and one with 16` ;)

Answer (score 12):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float  a=12.6664287277627762f;
        double b=12.6664287277627762;

        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
12.666429
12.666428727762776
```

float can handle about 7 decimal places. A double can handle about 16 decimal places.

Answer (score 5):

Doubles have twice the precision of  floats. Thus they have smaller rounding errors.

A float has (usually) 32 bits, and a double 64 (again usually). Thus floats have rounding errors on more numbers than doubles.

Comment: +1 in Java float is always 32-bit and double is always 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

Floats have less precision than doubles.

It's roughly half as much - 23 bits vs 52 for double(Thanks a lot Mr. Skeet!)!

[32-bit for floats, 64-bit for doubles.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) ...Remember that the word "float" has  fewer letters than "double", that's a "memory" trick :)

Comment: Not "half" - a `float` only has 23 bits of precision, and `double` has 52. It's not like the mantissa size is proportional to the overall size.