# Method overloading shows 'incompatible type error' with float but not with double

Tags: java, type-conversion

I tried this method overloading code and I got the error

> no suitable method found for add(double,double)

The code:

```
class Adder {
    static float add(float a, float b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    static int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}

class TestOverloading1 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(Adder.add(11.5, 11.5));
        System.out.println(Adder.add(27, 21));
    }
}
```

On writing, **11.5f** in params, this works well.

I understood the differences between float and double from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27598078/1999190) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11581337/1999190).

So, why does Java take the parameters as double datatype by default? Is the higher precision of double behind such a bias?

I am aware that it takes the double by default. But, I wish to know what is the reason behind this?

Comment: because 11.5 is a double. you can also try with: new Float(11.5)

Comment: @Stultuske Suggesting people to use `new Float(11.5)` is bad advice, why introduce a new wrapper object, when using a float literal will do.

Comment: it wasn't really advice, more a hint that it's a more 'visible' way of testing whether for a float it would work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A floating point literal without any suffix (such as `11.5`) is of type `double` by definition (similarly an integer literal without any suffix is of type `int`).

A `double` parameter is not acceptable for a method that accepts `float` arguments (since a casting from `double` to `float` may result in loss of data, and therefore the compiler won't perform such casting automatically).

On the other hand, `11.5f` is a `float` literal, so you can pass such literals to your `add(float a,float b)` method.

Answer (score 4):

doing

```
Adder.add(11.5,11.5)
```

is the same as

```
double a = 11.5;
double b = 11.5;
Adder.add(a, b)
```

that doesnt match the parameters in the static method

```
static float add(float a,float b){return a+b;}
```

so you are required to:
cast those literals to float:

```
Adder.add(11.5f, 11.5f );
```

or declare a and b as float

```
float a = 11.5;
float b = 11.5;
Adder.add(a, b)
```

Answer (score 2):

"11.5" without nothing is considerated as double by Java.
You can use something as :

```
System.out.println(Adder.add(new Float(11.5),new Float(11.5)));
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java when we type decimal number as 11.5, then it is considered as double. double is 64-bit while float is 32-bit so conversion is not possible, that's why compile time exception occurs. For more info please visit : [Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is just a specification. Just like why `int` have default value 0 in Java.

Double is the default type for decimal values:

> double: The double data type is a double-precision 64-bit IEEE 754
>   floating point. Its range of values is beyond the scope of this
>   discussion, but is specified in the Floating-Point Types, Formats, and
>   Values section of the Java Language Specification. **For decimal values,
>   this data type is generally the default choice**. As mentioned above,
>   this data type should never be used for precise values, such as
>   currency.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html